# Linq Performance with predicates

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, linq

I'm refactoring a project at the moment, which has a lot of very similar queries on a page

```
db.WF_Process.Where(x=>x.WorkflowProcessState == 
(int)WorkflowProcessStateEnum.SubtitleFileVersion && 
x.WorkflowProcessSubState == (int)SubtitleFileProcessEnum.SubtitleQCReferred).Count();

db.WF_Process.Where(x=>x.WorkflowProcessState == 
(int)WorkflowProcessStateEnum.SubtitleFileVersion &&
x.WorkflowProcessSubState == (int)SubtitleFileProcessEnum.QCUserFailed).Count();
```

This produces the following SQL which runs very quick

```
SELECT 
[GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1]
FROM ( SELECT 
    COUNT(1) AS [A1]
    FROM [dbo].[WF_Process] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE (4 = [Extent1].[WorkflowProcessState]) AND (119 = [Extent1].[WorkflowProcessSubState])
)  AS [GroupBy1]
```

//Repeat the above queries with 100 different enum values

To clean up the code a bit i've refactored it into the below method

```
 private int GetSubtitleProcessCount(Func<WF_Process, bool> predicate)
        {
            return
                db.WF_Process.Where(x => x.WorkflowProcessState == (int)WorkflowProcessStateEnum.SubtitleFileVersion)
                    .Where(predicate)
                    .Count();
        }
```

Called like this

```
model.SubtitleQCReferred = GetSubtitleProcessCount(x=> x.WorkflowProcessSubState == (int)SubtitleFileProcessEnum.SubtitleQCReferred);
```

This however produces this SQL

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[ProcessID] AS [ProcessID], 
[Extent1].[MaterialID] AS [MaterialID], 
[Extent1].[VideoVersionID] AS [VideoVersionID], 
[Extent1].[AudioVersionID] AS [AudioVersionID], 
[Extent1].[TXVersionID] AS [TXVersionID], 
[Extent1].[XMLVersionID] AS [XMLVersionID], 
[Extent1].[SubtitleVersionID] AS [SubtitleVersionID], 
[Extent1].[Progress] AS [Progress], 
[Extent1].[ProcessStatusDescription] AS [ProcessStatusDescription], 
[Extent1].[WorkflowProcessState] AS [WorkflowProcessState], 
[Extent1].[WorkflowProcessSubState] AS [WorkflowProcessSubState], 
[Extent1].[ProcessState] AS [ProcessState], 
[Extent1].[ProcessStateDateLastModified] AS [ProcessStateDateLastModified], 
[Extent1].[DateCreated] AS [DateCreated], 
[Extent1].[DateLastChecked] AS [DateLastChecked], 
[Extent1].[SleepUntil] AS [SleepUntil], 
[Extent1].[LongRunningProcessID] AS [LongRunningProcessID]
FROM [dbo].[WF_Process] AS [Extent1]
WHERE 4 = [Extent1].[WorkflowProcessState]
```

Which retrieves the entire record set and then performs the count in code.

I'm assuming this is to do with the second where clause. Why is this?

Is there any way of keeping the pattern i'm using (with small) modification so it  produces decent SQL?

Comment: from the looks of it, your code *should* be producing the right sql to run the count on SQL instead of in memory. One of your predicates is causing it to enumerate in code because it couldn't be converted to sql for some reason, but they look like they should be valid.

Comment: Instead of `Func<WF_Process>` try using `Expression<Func<WF_Process>>`. The where you are using is linq to objects.

Comment: oh, i know why. because the `Where(Func<>)` is an in-memory extension. you want `Where(Expression<Func<>>)` instead

Comment: Out of curiosity. Care to lighten why there are counts retrieved in such manner for hundreds of times, if they are all matching the same field or that it is just a coincidence that you gave 2 examples which are? It should be way more efficient to use group by and get all counts at once and then just assign the counts to the model from the in memory collection?

Comment: They're not checking the same field in my example.

Comment: They are? WorkflowProcessState and WorkflowProcessSubState, just the SubtitleFileProcessEnum changes?

Comment: Hence why I wanted to refactor it, there's 35 queries which check the workflowprocessstate to be equal to subtitle, and each one has a different workflowprocesssubstate to check against.

Comment: Shouldn't 1 query to db be enough then? which groups it by subtitle and workflowprocesssubstate, and returns the workflowprocesssubstate number and count?

Comment: Right, I see what you're driving at. There's definitely scope for cutting the number of queries down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the accepted type of the method to be `Expression<Func<WF_Process, bool>>` it should properly convert the `Count` logic to SQL.

i.e.:

```
GetSubtitleProcessCount(Expression<Func<WF_Process, bool>> predicate)
```

[The documentation on `PredicateBuilder`](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) has some more info about this.

Comment: Thanks will test and accept, when I get back from lunch